# Storing Site Global Variables

Tags: php, mysql, yii, global-variables

Quick question - I'm trying to decide the best way to store some site variables. I would like build a "control panel" type feature into my site where I can chose settings and they will be reflected throughout my site.

For example -  I have one item I'm selling and it has a price (and a picture to display the price). I would like to be able to set this global variable from a custom backend page instead of having to go and change the img src etc..

What is the best way to go about doing this? At first I thought a DB table but then surely it would be a slow(ish) way of accessing only a handful of site variables? I also thought about a file, but was wondering how I would go about overwriting the correct bit when values change etc.

Using your expertise, please could you recommend an avenue to go down (if there is a favourable method), many thanks! (I'm using the Yii framework if anyone else uses it too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look into using a properties (.ini) file.

The function `parse_ini_file(string $filename)` returns an array of the properties stored by an .ini file.

However, php doesn't have a function to write ini files included, so you will need a custom one.  [Here](http://pinoytech.org/blog/post/Write-INI-files-with-PHP) is one, `write_ini_file(array $assoc_arr, string $path)` which adds an arrays keys and values to the ini file at the given path, replacing old key values with new ones if necessary.

Comment: Thanks. I looked into this and it seemed very promising until I couldn't find how to write back to an ini file using PHP? Is there a way to write back (overwrite existing value)?

Comment: Edited my answer to include how to write to ini files.

Comment: No problem.  You may wish to mark it as accepted so nobody wastes unnecessary time posting more answers.

Comment: Have to wait 3 minutes unfortunately! Will do then

Comment: Personally I think you should avoid adding any code that writes to the disk. A table is a much easier way as it won't have to be parsed every request and you only load settings you actually need. There is a pretty good chance that the reading of the file + parsing will be slower than a table. The table will probably be kept loaded in RAM as its used a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Storing site variables in database isn't a bad idea. If you're concerned about performance, you could cache those values using [memcached](http://memcached.org/) to avoid extra database hits and then you'd only need to invalidate the cached values properly depending on your usage scenario.

Refer to the following article for more information: [PHP Performance Series: Caching Techniques](http://blog.digitalstruct.com/2008/02/27/php-performance-series-caching-techniques/).

Comment: I was thinking how to implement it.. All I could really think of was either: a 1 row table where the columns are for a different variable; or a 2 column table where columns are "Variable" "Value" (or along those lines).. is any way better than the other?

Comment: I prefer key/value pairs as I think they're are easier to use. As long as everything is cached, performance difference in retrieving the values for the first time (one row with many columns vs multiple rows with 3 columns [id, key, value]) will be negligible.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements are very similar to what mine were. Inspired from the settings extension ( http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/settings/ ), I created my own settings API that is available throughout the application. See this https://github.com/xtranophilist/awecms/blob/f9bfc5a09bf050373b710ca15f6685ad8fea9fcd/protected/components/Settings.php
The get, set and delete methods are very flexible and can do bulk operations too.

It also has automatic type detection and the set values can be managed from the backend (which is the admin module).